# whats with CSS position: absolute and relative with both classes and id's?

Tags: jquery, css

I was just doing a little jQuery test but this "weird" css problem came in front. I wanted to constrain my dialogBox divs with some positioned parent divs so that they dont move when I toggle the children on and off with jQuery. First problem was with just floating or with relative positioning, was that jQuery toggling did some weird things to the togglees brothers, they went up and down with the animation and I thought that lets force it with absolute to the class they share. Nice, so they collapsed on eachother and I try to separate them by giving them accordingly left: values to get them back to orig. places. But they don't do nothing. I've gone backandforvard the document and browsers devel-tools and seems that for some reason the DOM doesn't take my left: value into account. 
And its that none the newest firefox, chrome, IE, Opera nor Safari understand it. The left: values work ofcourse when added to the boxShell class where the absolute positioning was declared, but not when added to corresponding id's... Please help:

```js
$(function() {
 
 
 $('.btn').on('click', function() {
        var boxId = $(this).attr('data-boxId');
        $('#'+boxId).toggle(1000);
    });
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1080px;
    height: 3000px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#boxWrapper {
 width: 620px;
 height: 350px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.boxShell {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

.boxShell#1 {
    left: 0px;
}

.boxShell#2 {
    left: 200px;
}

.boxShell#3 {
    left: 400px;
}

.box {
 width: 200px;
 height: 300px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #99FFFF;
}

.boxTop {
 height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
 background-color: #00FFFF;
}

.box .boxTop h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "arial", "Helvetica", "sans-serif";
 
}

#buttonWrapper {
 width: 742px;
    height: 150px;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.btn {
 margin: 30px;
 padding: 20px 50px;
 font-size: 30px;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fi">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQueryTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/actions.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="boxWrapper">
            <div class="boxShell" id="1">
                <div class="box" id="box1">
                    <div class="boxTop">
                        <h1>#box1</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxShell" id="2">
                <div class="box" id="box2">
                    <div class="boxTop">
                        <h1>#box2</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="boxShell" id="3">
                <div class="box" id="box3">
                    <div class="boxTop">
                        <h1>#box3</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </div>
  <div id="buttonWrapper">
  <button class="btn" id="btn1" data-boxId="box1">#btn1</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn2" data-boxId="box2">#btn2</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn3" data-boxId="box3">#btn3</button>
  </div>
    </div>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So... what's the problem? I just played with the snippet and don't really see an issue.

Comment: There should be 3 panels and one button for each. but they are on top of each other because the .boxShell#1,2 and 3 left: values don't work. why is that they are overrun by something else? it works from .boxshell but not when I add the id (#1#2#3) to the selector... :o